# Validate pydantic field against a list of values

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I would like to query the Meals database table to obtain a list of meals (i.e. 1= breakfast, 2= lunch, 3= dinner, etc.), and validate the Recipe meal_id contains one of these values. Is this possible? Any suggestions how?

```
# Models

class Meal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "meals"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True, unique=True)

class Recipe(Base):
    __tablename__ = "recipes"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    note = Column(String, nullable=True)
    star = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    meal_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("meals.id"), nullable=True)
    details = relationship("RecipeIngredient")
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))

# Schemas

class Meal(BaseModel):
    name: str

class Recipe(BaseModel):
    name: str
    note: Optional[str] = None
    star: Optional[bool] = False
    meal_id : Optional[str] = None
```

Comment: Have you seen the Enum support in Pydantic? https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#enums-and-choices The `ToolEnum` should be an exact match to what you're trying to do? (if you want to use a string instead, which I would recommend, the `FruitEnum` does what you want to do).

Comment: This is pretty close. Would you query the DB for the list of values and then build an ENum based on that? Or such validation should be done within the view?

Comment: If there are no access controls required (i.e. all meals are available for all users), and your database enforces the foreign key relationship, you could just insert it and catch the error. However, regardless of access control, I'd have a `Depends` on my view that resolves the given `meal_id` - for example (`meal: Meal = Depends(get_meal_from_data)` and if required, takes the current user into account.